# Not able to fix the issue in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a batch class and I wrote test class for the same. The test class is throwing an error at Date Type. Can someone help me how to fix the issue.

**Batch Class**

```
public without sharing class EtcObjectBatchProcess implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    public String action;
    public Date startDt;
    public Date endDt;
    public EtcObjectBatchProcess(String operation, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
        action = operation;
        startDt = startDate;
        endDt = endDate;
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {        
        String query = '';
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
            query = 'SELECT Id, CreatedDate, Qualification__c FROM Registration__c';
        }
        else {
            query = 'SELECT Id, CreatedDate, Qualification__c FROM Registration__c '+
                    + 'WHERE CreatedDate >=:' + startDt + 'AND CreatedDate <=:' + endDt;
        }
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    *public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Registration__c> records) {
        
        List<Registration__c> deleteList = new List<Registration__c>();
        List<Registration__c> updatedList = new List<Registration__c>();
        for(Registration__c rec : records) {
            if(action == 'delete') {
                deleteList.add(rec);
            }
            else if(action == 'reprocess') {
                if(rec.Qualification__c == '' || rec.Qualification__c == NULL) {
                    rec.Qualification__c = 'MBA';
                    updatedList.add(rec);
                }
            }
        }
        if(deleteList.size() > 0) {
            delete deleteList;
        }
        if(updatedList.size() > 0) {
            update updatedList;
        }
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    }
}*
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class EtcObjectBatchProcessTest {
    public static testMethod void method1() {
        List<Registration__c> regList = new List<Registration__c>();
        regList.add(new Registration__c(First_Name__c = 'Test', Qualification__c = ''));
        regList.add(new Registration__c(First_Name__c = 'Test1', Qualification__c = ''));
        insert regList;
        
        Test.startTest();
        Database.executeBatch(new EtcObjectBatchProcess('reprocess', Date.today(), Date.today().addDays(-10)));
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

I am running the batch based on parameters form the Vf Page and the highlighted lines are not getting covered. Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Can you add the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: I am getting "System.QueryException: unexpected token: '2021-04-05' " while running the batch class and it also throws an error at Line 19 of batch class.

Comment: You are passing the Start Date as Date.Today() and End Date as Date.Today().addDays(-10). 
This means the end date is 10 days before the start date. The Query will not return any records, or only the records where CreatedDate = today. Are you sure this is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant:

```
if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
```

instead of:

```
if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
```

Please be aware that this is definitely not considered a best practice.

In addition, your query is malformed:

```
+ 'WHERE CreatedDate >=:' + startDt + 'AND CreatedDate <=:' + endDt;
```

Ends up rendering as something like:

```
WHERE CreatedDate >=:2021-04-16AND CreatedDate <=:2021-04-06
```

Which is an invalid SOQL statement, both because of the colons and the lack of a space in the query.

Either use proper binding, or format the dates correctly (not both):

```
+ 'WHERE CreatedDate >=:startDt AND CreatedDate <=:endDt';
```

Or:

```
+ 'WHERE CreatedDate >= '+startDt+' AND CreatedDate <= '+endDt;
```

Note also that your test has the filters backwards. The end date occurs before the start date, so no records will match this query.

```
WHERE CreatedDate >= 2021-04-16 AND CreatedDate <= 2021-04-16
```

This will never be true, so no records will match. This is another reason why your query would return no results, and execute won't be called.

---

Your code is unnecessarily complicated, and should be fixed:

```
public without sharing class EtcObjectBatchProcess implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    String action;
    Date startDt;
    Date endDt;
    public EtcObjectBatchProcess(String operation, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
        action = operation;
        startDt = startDate;
        endDt = endDate;
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            SELECT Qualification__c 
            FROM Registration__c
            WHERE CreatedDate >= :startDt AND CreatedDate <= endDt
        ]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Registration__c> records) {
        switch on action {
            when 'delete' {
                delete records;
            }
            when 'reprocess' {
                Registration__c[] updates = new Registration__c[0];
                for(Registration__c record: records) {
                    if(record.Qualification__c == null) {
                        updates.add(record);
                        record.Qualification__c = 'MBA';
                    }
                }
                update updates;
            }
        }
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    }
}
```

And your unit test can be fixed:

```
@isTest
public class EtcObjectBatchProcessTest {
    public static testMethod void method1() {
        List<Registration__c> regList = new List<Registration__c>();
        regList.add(new Registration__c(First_Name__c = 'Test', Qualification__c = ''));
        regList.add(new Registration__c(First_Name__c = 'Test1', Qualification__c = ''));
        insert regList;
        
        Test.startTest();
        Database.executeBatch(new EtcObjectBatchProcess('reprocess', Date.today().addDays(-10), Date.today()));
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have understood what mistake I made...